# Django/i18n: how to translate method result in a template?

Tags: django, methods, internationalization

I am working on internationalization of my project.
There is something I do not understand even reading Django documentation

I have a view where I pass a context (a list)

In my template, I loop on this list and run a method on each element of my list
this method return a string ('string#1' or 'string#2' depending of the element)

I would like to translate (en/fr) but I did not understand how to do it?
Should I apply the translation in my models or in the template?

Below a simplified code for an example

models.py

```
class mymodel(models.Model)
    def mymethod(self):
        condition = othermodel.objects.get(pk=self.ide)
        if condition == 1 :
            return 'string#1' # the string I want to translate
        else:
            return 'string#2' # the string I want to translate
        return ''
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    mylist= _(["elt#1","elt#2","elt#3","elt#4","elt#5"])
    return render(request, 'myapp/test.html', {'mylist': mylist})
```

test.html

```
{% for element in mylist %}
    {{ element.mymethod }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Jacek answer is good if you want to use the i18n way, another option is [django-modeltranslation package](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it allow translation to be apply on the django models side, so it help when implement for example API, frontend and database

Answer (score 0):

you can choose one of the options

If you want translate in **model**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class mymodel(models.Model)
    def mymethod(self):
        condition = othermodel.objects.get(pk=self.ide)
        if condition == 1 :
            return _('string#1') # the string I want to translate
        else:
            return _('string#2') # the string I want to translate
        return ''
```

If you want translate in **view**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def test(request):
    mylist= [_("elt#1"), _("elt#2"), _("elt#3"), _("elt#4"), _("elt#5")]
    return render(request, 'myapp/test.html', {'mylist': mylist})
```

If you want translate in **template**

```
{% load i18n %}

{% for element in mylist %}
    {% trans element.mymethod %}
{% endfor %}
```